# literalinclude and absolute paths to files on Linux

Tags: python-sphinx, absolute-path

I would like to use Sphinx to document the changes I do to my Ubuntu installation, such as network configuration, apache site configuration, supporting scripts etc.

In order to do this I would like to have `literalinclude` access the system / structure, in the same way as this is possible under Windows using something like

```
.. literalinclude:: C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\sphinx\legacy\scripts\xyz_00.sh
   :language: bash
   :linenos:
   :lineno-match:
   :start-after: # LOG START
   :end-before: # LOG END
   :emphasize-lines: 10-13
```

Is there any way to do this? An alternative perspective on the task?

I thought about including a symbolic link to system / under the source home but ... it seems neverending as I guess it traverses the whole system.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) says: "The file name is usually relative to the current file’s path. However, if it is absolute (starting with /), it is relative to the top source directory". On Windows, an absolute path such as `C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\xyz_00.sh` works. But on Linux, an absolute path such as `/home/XYZ/xyz_00.sh` does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems neverending"?